# Does query optimization phase consider this?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a date column `StartDate` indexed. I was just wondering how the query optimization phase handles queries of the following form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <dbo.TABLE> 
WHERE (StartDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-10')
OR (StartDate BETWEEN '2010-01-05' AND '2010-01-15')
```

There is an overlap between the two dates. Should I be doing the optimization myself of giving it the dates as `(StartDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-15')` or can the SQL engine optimize this by itself?

Comment: What does the execution plan show?

Comment: It shows me the same plan. Actually, let me dig deeper into each components and get back in a minute.

Comment: Ok, so it shows the same I/O and CPU cost. Guess you made me answer my own question.

Comment: Try it with variables now: should differ. SQL Server can optimise for constants but aims for re-use with variables. So the plan is more general for a range of values, including things like end < start etc

Comment: Yes it did! The CPU cost increased from `0.975` to `1.986` when I used variables. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Answer added: it was easier to use comments for the back-and-forth. It was better to use your data in your table rather than some I concocted :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare it with variables and constants: the plans should differ.

SQL Server can optimise for constants but aims for re-use with variables. So the plan is more general with variables. When constants are used, a "generalised reusable plan" isn't required because if the constants change it will be a new plan

A "variable" plan won't consider conditions like `end < start` which would be short circuited with constants.

As noted in comments to the question, behaviour is as expected

You should make the same happen for constants with "[Forced Parameterization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037%28SQL.90%29.aspx)", but I haven't tried.